# How can particular domain email ids in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I get only @gmail.com email addresses from a table containing user email id's in SQL:

```
SELECT     UserID, UserName, Email
FROM         Users
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this... the LIKE clause gets the records which have gmail.com endings :)

```
SELECT UserID, 
       UserName, 
       Email
FROM Users
WHERE Email LIKE '%gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT UserID,
       UserName,
       Email
FROM Users
WHERE
   Email LIKE '%@gmail.com';
```

See this SQLFiddle : [**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08748/2)

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    UserID, UserName, Email 
FROM Users
WHERE right(Email, 10)='@gmail.com'
```